# Ссылка в отдельном окне html,css,reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Как сделать так чтобы ссылка по нажатию на input или button открывалась в таком вот окошке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который я использую:

```
import logo from './neloda.png';
import './App.css';
import discord from './i.jpg';
import login from './login.jpg';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
function App() {
    function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('По ссылке кликнули.');
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript/14132265#14132265', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
  }
  return (
  <div>
    
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Share Page
     </button>
    </div>
);
  }


export default App;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132265/7791165

Comment: на реакте это почему-то не работает

Comment: так какая разница реакт или не реакт. Покажите код

Comment: можете посмотреть код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript/14132265#14132265 ','','Toolbar=1,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0,Width=570,Height=520');"
```